# Add a pointer/arrow showing the data on Linechart Flutter

Tags: flutter, fl-chart

I want to add a pointer in my FlChart LineChart .
Like this [image]

I've used fl_chart for the same
And it's output is
[image]

Comment: Are you making charts for an application like TradingView?